# vcl.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++builder, vcl

I'm looking to compile some old source code in Visual C++.  However, the first of many errors I am receiving is:

```
vcl.h: No such file or directory
```

This appears to be in reference to the Visual Component Library, native to Borland compilers it seems.  I downloaded the free Borland C++ 5.5 command line compiler, but it doesn't seem to contain a vlc.h in its include directory.

How can I resolve my issue?  Many thanks.

Comment: At a guess, it is part of C++ Builder. You almost certainly won't be able to compile C++ Builder code with VC++.

Comment: Agreed.  VCL is Borland-specific and will not compile in other compilers.  The free Borland compilers do not ship with VCL (but can compile VCL if you have it pre-installed from another Borland product).

Answer (score 4):

This old code must have come from C++Builder. If it actually uses the VCL, you won't be able to build it with any other compiler. If there are other VCL includes like classes.hpp, system.hpp, controls.hpp, etc. it is using the VCL.

If it is a console application and doesn't actually **use** any VCL classes, then you can probably just remove the include, but the chances are slim.

Answer (score 2):

Borland C++ 5.5 and C++ Builder are two different products.

The VCL components are in the C++ Builder product and can't be compiled with Borland C++ 5.5 which is a pure C/C++ compiler (I think OWL is included there).

So you have to get your hands on C++ Builder to be able to compile it.