# Build Eclipse C++ Docfrac project using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio, compiler-construction

Can someone please help me understand how to build the open source Docfrac C++ Eclipse project with Visual Studio 2012?

[Docfrac](http://docfrac.net/wordpress/)

**UPDATE 1:**

When building project in VS 2012, I get:

*Unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "pch.h"' to your source?*

**UPDATE 2:** Got past above issues thanks to Rowland.

*Now i get, could not open #include **vcl.h**. No such file or directory.*

**CLOSING COMMENTS:**

Unfortunately, what I wanted to achieve is not directly possible. Thanks to Rowland for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what it is you're having trouble with? Reference a particular step in the instructions if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the error relating to precompiled headers, select the source code files (.cpp or .c) that you added to the project in the Solution Explorer. Then right-click, choose Properties. Then in the C/C++ section under Precompiled Headers, select the option that says "Not using precompiled headers". Rebuild and bingo.

[image: Screenshot]

Alternatively, you can right-click the project itself and set it for all files.

Comment: Thanks! Got past this point, now I get could not open #include <vcl.h>. No such file or directory. Is this a standard header, or do you think its specific to this project, as I cant find it anywhere.

Comment: Well I don't have it in the Win8 SDK with my VS2012 installation. What file `#include`'s it? Does it build if you comment it out?

Comment: It's being reference all over the project, so it would be difficult to remove. There's tons of files!

Comment: Smells like a Borland header, that's all VCL stuff. Relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/q/3441281/2065121

Comment: Damn! I'm out of luck. Compiling in VS 2012 was imperative for me. Do you perhaps know of a good open source Text Format Conversion tool, i.e. rtf to html to rtf, etc. This Docfrac seemed good.

Comment: Sorry - maybe post another question :-(

Comment: Hi I am the author of docfrac, vcl.h is indeed for an old version of Borland C++ Builder. There is a new version of the UI using QT. If you are interested in the SDK - I am happy to have another look at it but my download stats haven't shown much interest.